# Docker for Windows Network Slow

Tags: windows, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-for-windows, linux-containers

#### Expected behavior

I expect the ping to be the same on the host OS than in the Docker

#### Actual behavior

- I use Linux Container
- Ping Test done on www.google.com
- ping on the host OS : 6ms
- ping in the docker : 11ms

#### Information

- Windows Version: 10 build 1903
- Docker Desktop Version: 2.1.4.0

I have a Docker with Fedora 29 inside.

I observed that the ping in the docker is very high compare to the ping from the host OS.
Even when i ping a site like google, the ping is higher in docker.

I also try the ping with the fedora remix distribution in WSL 2 and the ping is the same than the host OS (6ms). 
WSL use Hyper-V also so i think the problem came from docker VM.

docker network : "bridge".
network card : vEthernet (Docker NAT)

I try to observe the network flow with wireshark.
On the ethernet adapter i see that the" requets ping" are the same on both Windows and Docker and the response time is the same.
But impossible to observe the packet transfert from "ethernet adapter" to "vEthernet DockerNAT" with wireshark.

This is a big problem for me because i use this docker for transferring file by sshfs and the download speed is 4 times slower with docker than WSL 2.

Do you have some idea ?

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: There is a performance cost because of the extra networking stacks introduced. Relative questions: [How to optimize performance for a docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21691540/how-to-optimize-performance-for-a-docker-container/21707838#21707838), [Performance issues running nginx in a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49023800/performance-issues-running-nginx-in-a-docker-container), [What is the runtime performance cost of a Docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21889053/what-is-the-runtime-performance-cost-of-a-docker-container)